# Start vs. Start Off?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What is the difference between `start` and `start off`. Both sound the same to me except `start off` sounds more informal. Is `off` here a filler word to make the sentence more natural?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Start off** is not simply the same as **start**.  It has two specific meanings:

1. To begin a series of steps, as in a recipe.  Example: "Start off by mixing together the vanilla and two eggs."  **Start** by itself is also acceptable in this sentence: "Start by mixing together the vanilla and two eggs."
2. To begin a trip, or journey.  Example: "We're starting off for Chicago today."

There are many cases where **start** is acceptable where **start off** sounds strange, means something different, or is outright wrong.  For example:

- "Start baking the cookies" means to begin the activity of baking the cookies.  "Start off baking the cookies" is also grammatical, but sounds like you're telling them which item to bake first, out of several options.
- "The race started" sounds normal, while "The race started off" sounds like something is missing on the end of the sentence, perhaps "The race started off poorly for Johnson."
- "Start the car" is acceptable, while "Start off the car" makes no sense.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference

Answer (score 0):

“Start off” is more like a formal and rich use while simply to use word “start” is informal, casual one . For series of actions there has to be a formal use while for a simple action which completes in one go one word “start” would do.

Comment: This is not true.  It has nothing to do with formality.  The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: Do you have any quotes or references to support your answer?