# When I was "starting out" or "starting off" or just "starting" - which one is correct to refer to a point in time?

Tags: phrases

How do I use the word "start" correctly in the following contexts?

> "When I was **starting/starting out/starting off** as a mixed martial arts student, I used to receive a lot of injuries."

> "You speak quite good English for a beginner (in English learning). I could not even introduce myself in English when I was **starting/starting out/starting off**."

I found a question about "start out" and "start off" [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/to-start-out-vs-to-start-off) but they were not used to refer to a point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your examples, "starting out" and "starting off" would be acceptable, but "*starting out*" is the better choice.

"Start off" usually means to begin something at an entry-level position, and it's used for contrast, like:

> "Norville Barnes **started off** as a mail clerk at the company, but ended up being the President."

or

> "I **started off** earning minimum wage at McDonald's, and through some lucky breaks and good networking, I now earn 10x that much as a lawyer."

On the other hand, "starting out" tends to just mean the beginning of being or doing something. Like:

> "I'm just **starting out** as an electrician, so I'm worried about making mistakes."

In both your examples, you describe something you started and continued to do. You started being a mixed martial artist and will continue to be a "mixed martial artist" no matter how good you get. It's the same with being an English student: no matter what your level, you're still called an "English student".

"Starting" is usually followed by what you're starting, usually with "just" for emphasis, so your example could be rewritten: "When I was (just) **starting to study martial arts**...".

Comment: thank you so much @gotube. Does that mean "You speak quite good English for a beginner (in English learning). I could not even introduce myself in English when I was starting out" is correct?

Comment: That's correct :)